# Charcter encoding, problem with locale on debian

Tags: character-encoding, debian

I use vps with debian 9, mariadb 10.3.x, php7.0 (standard LAMP). 
I had to do the update all packages. After remove and install and import database all charcters its look like: "Tch�rzewski"
I check encoding in database (is it set to utf8_general_ci) and all table have that same. In database i have of course correct version of strings. 
I also check locale this is output:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="UTF-8"
LC_TIME="UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="UTF-8"
LC_NAME="UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="UTF-8"
LC_ALL=UTF-8
```

I check every file (have meta utf-8) and in php in files i have ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8')
I try with

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

but this didnt help

What can i do now? I can reinstall server but I dont want to waste a lot of time for that

Answer (score 0):

I am solved problem with add to PDO mysql-attr_init_command. Now all pdo commands looks like:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='._DBHOST_.';port=8889;dbname='._DBNAME_, _DBUSER_, _DBPASS_, 
array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```